# SVG Drop Shadow Not Working On Mobile

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm fairly new working with svgs and so I started off by making one in Illustrator and then exporting it as an svg file. From there I added the code from the svg file into my website. Everything seemed to work perfectly for desktop, but when I viewed my website on my phone there was an issue with how the svg was rendered.

For this svg I gave it a drop shadow in Illustrator before I saved it as an svg. Doing that worked perfectly for desktop because the svg is rendered with the drop shadow I added. However, on mobile, the svg is rendered correctly except that the drop shadow is now missing.

I checked to see if the issue was browser dependent, because I viewed it the first time on my iPhone in Safari, but in Chrome it also doesn't render the drop shadow.

I tried searching Google, but couldn't seem to find the answer I was looking for as to why this was occurring.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Comment: Please post the code of the SVG